# Selecting DataGridViewRow at a selected Index

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, selectedindex

I am having problems selecting a row out of the DataGridView on a search. The data source is a DataTable from a database. I am using a search box that checks the DataGridView for a product matching the product key, and i want to select it if found.
Here is what i have:

```
private void search_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in products_dgv.Rows)
        {
            string tempCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //Code comparing
            if (tempCode == code_tb.Text) //Checks if code matchs the search code
            { 
                //I would like to do a products_dgv.selectedIndex = row.Index but it
                //doesnt work
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property of the `DataGridView` to set the selection. If you are using `FullRowSelect` as selection mode, just use any cells in the row that you would like to select.
For example:

```
...
if (tempCode == code_tb.Text) //Checks if code matchs the search code
{ 
     products_dgv.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
     break;
}
...
```